# Views rewrite results: div in anchor

Tags: views, navigation

I am trying to accomplish the following in a views accordion style.

[image]

> Here is what I am putting in the rewrite field

```
<div class="session-date">[field_event_date_1]</div>
<div class="session-title">[title]</div> 
<div class="session-timeslot">[field_time_slot_1]</div>
```

> Here is what gets rendered

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a class="accordion-toggle views-ajax-processed-processed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#views-bootstrap-accordion-1" href="#collapse0">
        Tuesday, November 3, 2015 
Example title description goes here
1A - 10:00 - 11:30 AM 
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
```

[image]

HTML5 spec allows div styling in anchors. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you don't use accordion, does the cessions classes get rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was purely about just views accordian, then the rendering output you show would not be showing a div with a class of panel-heading. I see this as more likely about trying to have a views accordian rewrite into a panel and probably panels accordian at the same time and having the anchor tag reduced to a single line output when the html is stripped out. So without knowing what the full details are I can only suggest trying the rewrite as:

```
[field_event_date_1]
[title]

[field_time_slot_1]
```

or if only the div tags are being stripped out then try:

```
<div class="session-date">[field_event_date_1]</div><br/>
<div class="session-title">[title]</div><br/>
<p><div class="session-timeslot">[field_time_slot_1]</div></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using bootstrap accordion which the module strips out any markup.
Although I could hardcode the example, it was pointless to do so in that module.  I ended up changing my styling and using views accordion which allowed more grouping options.